# hyperref - unicode and pdfencoding

Tags: hyperref

I have troubles with the encoding of the package `hyperref` with lualatex 1.12.0. I'm aware that I don't use the very latest version 7.00e. Instead I use version 7.00d.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} 

\hypersetup{
    pdfencoding={auto},
    pdfauthor={ABC – https...},
    pdftitle={title with German öäüß},
%   pdfencoding={auto}
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

In 7.00d `unicode` is not set as default therefore I set it manually. I'm curious why the order of the `pdfencoding` matters. If I place it the way as above than I get

[image]

but when I change the order and set the encoding below this works perfectly. But honestly I don't understand why I need this setting anyway

1. For the `pdfauthor` since there are no special chars included.
2. For the `pdftitle` unicode should be set as default - according to the documentation.

Comment: don't use `pdfencoding={auto},` with lualatex.

Comment: aha - thx for the hint. But where can I find any hints that I shouldn't use it?

Comment: I added it now to the documentation.

Comment: oh, good to know - thx.

Comment: Just a stupid q: Wouldn't it even be better if `hyperref` checks by itself if lualatex is running or not? And than ignore it accordingly.

Comment: the development code does this already.